# Winform DataGridViewLinkColumn ReadOnly property not working

Tags: winforms, datagridview, bindingsource, datagridviewlinkcolumn

In my VS2015 `Winform` app, there is one `DataGridView` control bound to a `BindingSource` that is bound to a SQL database. The Grid has four columns: ID, URL, Name, Type. The URL column is `DataGridViewLinkColumn` whose `ReadOnly` property, by default, is set to `False`. I can edit the Name and Type columns but URL columns shows as ReadOnly. Why? How can I make URL column editable?

Comment: `DataGridViewLinkColumn` is not editable. It only shows the content as a link.

Comment: Is the data actually being changed in the database (readwrite) or only on the form (could still be readonly, just "teasing" you)?

Answer (score 0):

As Reza stated:

> `DataGridViewLinkColumn` is not editable.

Therefore, to edit a cell in such a column you'll have to convert it to a `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` as needed. For instance, if I have subscribed to `DataGridView.CellContentClick` to handle clicking on a link, then I would handle `CellDoubleClick` for the cell conversion:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] == this.dataGridView1.Columns["URL"])
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        this.dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
    }
}
```

Once you've entered your value and left the cell, you should then use `CellValidated` to verify that the new value is a URI before converting the cell back to a `DataGridViewLinkCell`:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] == this.dataGridView1.Columns["URL"])
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

        if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(cell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute))
        {
            cell = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
        }
    }
}
```

**Caveat**:

- This only worked for me when the data for the "URL" column were strings and thus after binding, the column defaulted to a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` - forcing a manual conversion to link cells to begin with:

  ```
  private void DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
  {
      foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
      {
          if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(r.Cells["URL"].Value.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute))
          {
              r.Cells["URL"] = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Setting up the "URI" column as a `DataGridViewLinkColumn` from the beginning allowed for the conversion of cells to `TextBox` type successfully. But when converting back to link cells, debugging showed the conversion to happen, but the cell formatting and behavior failed.